# How to run a client side script when PayPal API V2 onApproval is completed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, paypal, devexpress

This is my current paypal script

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function populatePayPalButtons() {
  paypal.Buttons({
   createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
     purchase_units: [{
      description: 'Center Court Hire', 
      amount: { value: '30.00' }
     }]
    });
   },
   // --------- onApprove ---
   onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    // Capture the funds from the transaction
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
    // Call your server to save the transaction
    var url = 'http://localhost:50678/testPP.aspx';
    return fetch(url, {
       method: 'post',
       body: 'OrderData=30.00|Center Court|4698.01|4563' +'|' + data.orderID,
       headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });
   });
   },
   // --------- onCancel ---
   onCancel: function(data, actions) {
    // Show a cancel page, or return to cart
   },
   // --------- onError ---
   onError: function(err) {
    // Show an error page
    alert('An error has occurred');
   }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
 }
</script>
```

The button is displayed in an ASPxPopupControl. I have a script that will close that ASPxPopupControl and what I need is a way to execute that script as the final call in the onApprove function above.

If that is not possible, is there an event I can use/call to close the ASPxPopupControl without the user clicking a button.

There just doesn't seem a way to detect within the ASPxPopupControl that PayPal has finished processing.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function populatePayPalButtons() {
  paypal.Buttons({
   createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
     purchase_units: [{
      description: 'Court 4 Hire', 
      amount: { value: '50.00' }
     }]
    });
   },
   // --------- onApprove ---
   onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:50678/testPP.aspx';
    // Capture the funds from the transaction
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
    // Call your server to save the transaction
    CloseAndReturnToParentPage();
    return fetch(url, {
       method: 'post',
       headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
       body: 'OrderData=50.00|Court 4|4731.01|4563' +'|' + data.orderID,
    });
   });
   },
   // --------- onCancel ---
   onCancel: function(data, actions) {
    // Show a cancel page, or return to cart
   },
   // --------- onError ---
   onError: function(err) {
    // Show an error page
    alert('PayPal: An error has occurred! ');
   }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
 }
</script>
```

On called page:

```js
  function CloseAndReturnToParentPage() {
   var parentWindow = window.parent;
   parentWindow.SelectAndClosePopup('Finished');
  }
```

On calling page:

```js
 function SelectAndClosePopup(value) {
  if (value == "Finished")
   popupControlGetPayment.Hide();
  else { }

  cbPanel.PerformCallback('PayPalCompleted|Paid')
 }
```